# Select people whose birth dates are +/- 5 years (of a PHP dob variable)

Tags: php, mysql

So let's say my DoB is 1975-04-28, stored in variable `$dob`

I want to fetch people who are born +/- 5 years, so between 1970-04-28 and 1980-04-28.

Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT id, username FROM tusers 
WHERE profile_picture IS NOT NULL
AND settings LIKE '1,%' 
AND sex = :sex
AND last_visit BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Thank you

Edit: People's DoB are stored as `dob` column in the DB, on this format: 1989-06-30.

Edit2: I don't have a WHERE dob clause in the query because everything I've tried so far failed.

Comment: Why all the down votes and then a close vote? This question is perfectly within the scope and demonstrates their effort as well. Why discourage someone for a good question?

Comment: I have tried a couple of things. Such as DATEDIFF and other, but I failed. I am not sure how to fit my dob variable with people's stored DoB.

Comment: You have no DOB WHERE clause?

Comment: @zzlalani you're reading it wrong ;)

Comment: Back to +/- 5. Made a mistake putting another date when copy/pasting from my DB to showcase the format.

Comment: zzalani -- the date was fine at the start, and he read the fine date. You came after him and read my mistaken date ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WHERE dob BETWEEN ? - INTERVAL 5 YEAR AND ? + INTERVAL 5 YEAR
```

The `?`s represent anonymous placeholders, to be parameterised with your `$dob` variable upon execution.  Given that you are using named placeholders (e.g. `:sex`) elsewhere, you may wish to use named placeholders here too—but bear in mind that you cannot use the same parameter name multiple times, so you would have to use e.g. `:dob1` and `:dob2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from  tbl 
        where  dob 
        between  DATE_ADD(givendate,INTERVAL -5 YEAR) 
        and      DATE_ADD(givendate,INTERVAL +5 YEAR)
```